# how to create relationship in vba for excel?

Tags: excel, vba

let's call this table1:

```
|111|222|333|444|555
--------------------
|6  |6  |4  |3  |3
```

now lets say i have another table, and i need to use the information from both of them,
table2:

```
111|aaa  
222|bbb   
333|ccc  
444|ddd     
555|eee
```

I want the result table to look like this:
result table:

```
aaa|6   
bbb|6   
ccc|4    
ddd|3       
eee|3
```

any ideas?

Comment: @Math .. it means `555|eee` ..

Comment: What do you mean be a "table" in Excel? (I know what a table is, but in Excel the term is ambiguous) And what do you mean by a "result table"? Give us an example of how this should work operationally (again, it's ambiguous because there are so many different ways/things this could mean).

Comment: Do you want a VBA answer or are worksheet functions okay?

Comment: i want to learn both ways, i would love to see a VBA answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a direct reference to get the first column of your results table:

[image]

For the second column, use combination of `Index`, `Match`, and `HLookup` functions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HLOOKUP`.

For example, if you first table is in A1:E2 then you can use:

```
     A     B    C    D    E
1    111   222  333  444  555
2    6     6    4    3    3
3
4
5    111   aaa  =HLOOKUP(A5,$A$1:$E$2,20 //Returns 6
6    222   bbb
7    333   ccc
8    444   ddd
9    555   eee
```

Just drag down the formula.